# Implementing a method that escapes single quotes in a string

Tags: java

Background: In tcsh we can use single quotes inside single quote like this (like it said [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187651/how-to-echo-single-quote-when-using-single-quote-to-wrap-special-characters-in)):

```
echo 'It'\''s Shell Programming'
```

I want to create a method which escapes single quotes and prints it into a tcsh script I build on fly with Java. It should do:

1. If there is a `\'` (two chars) in the string, it will escape it so: `\'\''`.
2. If there is a `'` (one char with no `\` before it)  in the string, it will escape it so `'\''`.

I wrote the following method to do so:

```
private static String escapeStr(final String str) {
    String result = "";
    for (int index = 0; index < str.length(); ++index) {
        if (str.charAt(index) == '\\') {
            if (index + 1 < str.length() && str.charAt(index + 1) == '\'') {
                result += "\\'\\\''";
                index++;
            } else {
                result += str.charAt(index);
            }
        } else if (str.charAt(index) == '\'') {
            result += "'\\\''";
        } else {
            result += str.charAt(index);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

It looks like it does the job but I really don't like how I implemented it. It's hard to read as it has quite a lot of `\` chars. Also I do `index++` inside the  loop which feels like bad design. Is there a better approach here?

I will add that I want to call the method like so:

```
fileWriter.write("echo '" + escapeStr(cmd) + "'\n");
```

The whole point of this part is so the escape will print the `cmd` as-is. I wrap the command with `'` so it won't evaluate stuff like environment variables. So if the cmd already contains single quote it will fail. I will need to escape single quotes and that what I tried to do.

Comment: Beside the fact that I find it weird do do this "on the fly" in Java (outside of a more complex application) have you ever heard of [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)  and their [look ahead/behind](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) feature?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle My tool written in Java and creates tcsh scripts (aside with other stuff it does). How would you use look_ahead/behind here?

Comment: Sometimes the idea that comes to mind first is not the best, so look ahead/behind may not hold the expectation... ;o)

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest a Solution based on *regular expressions* like this:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers;
import org.junit.Test;

public class EscapeQuotesTest {

    Pattern escapedQuotePattern = Pattern.compile("(\\\\)?(')(')");

    private String escapeString(String input) {
        Matcher escapedQuote = escapedQuotePattern.matcher(input);
        escapedQuote.find();
        Optional<String> escapeChar = Optional.ofNullable(escapedQuote.group(1));
        String result = String.format("%s%s\\'%s", escapeChar.orElse(""), escapedQuote.group(2), escapedQuote.group(3));
        return result;
    }

    @Test
    public void preseveLeadingBackslash() {
        String input = "\\''";
        String result = escapeString(input);
        assertThat(" The escape char survived", result, CoreMatchers.containsString("\\'\\''"));
    }

    @Test
    public void noLeadingBackslash() {
        String input = "''";
        String result = escapeString(input);
        assertThat("no escape char at beginning", result, CoreMatchers.containsString("'\\''"));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's still hard to read and also you will need to add try-catch no?

Comment: @vesii *"It's still hard to read"* yes, you cannot go around the combined escaping needs for Java Strings and Regular Expression special chars. **---** *"you will need to add try-catch no?"* I wrote an SSCCE so no, a `try/catch` block is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

When you find the `\'` sequence, you're handling it all in one go.  This seems to be the source of your `index++` issue.  It also means that you've got the repeated `else` clause in there. A small improvement would be to only handle the `\` when you encounter `\'`, then handle the subsequent `'` on the next pass around the loop.  As far as I can tell handling for `'` doesn't really depend on what character was before it.  So, you'd end up with:

```
private static String escapeStr(final String str) {
    String result = "";
    for (int index = 0; index < str.length(); ++index) {
        if (str.charAt(index) == '\\' &&
                (index + 1 < str.length() && str.charAt(index + 1) == '\'')) {
            result += "\\";
        } else if (str.charAt(index) == '\'') {
            result += "'\\''";
        } else {
            result += str.charAt(index);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

You're also building up a `String` in a loop, rather than using a `StringBuilder`.  For small strings this probably won't make a lot of difference, however it can add up for big ones.  If you wanted to use `StringBuilder` it would look like:

```
private static String escapeStr(final String str) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int index = 0; index < str.length(); ++index) {
        if (str.charAt(index) == '\\' &&
                (index + 1 < str.length() && str.charAt(index + 1) == '\'')) {
            result.append("\\");
        } else if (str.charAt(index) == '\'') {
            result.append("'\\''");
        } else {
            result.append(str.charAt(index));
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Is it recommended to use StringBuilder here? If so, how would you do it?

Comment: @vesii I've added the StringBuilder version.  Generally, StringBuilder is faster when you're building up large Strings, bit by bit because it optimises out a lot of the reallocations which are required by immutable `Strings`.  When you're performing a small number there's not a lot of difference, and ocassionally using Strings will be faster, but generally if you're looping I'd expect a `StringBuilder` (but you have a better idea how big the scripts are and if it'll really make a difference).  `StringBuilder`s can be harder for some people to read than normal `String` concatenation.